# Button can't work in Chrome (Jquery/Javascript/css/php)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I code a simple blog with php and jquery/javascript ,
and I put a button under the bottom every posts, but I can't click the button on my top post and I have no idea which part has problem....

my test blog url is here:
http://japan-adventuretime.rhcloud.com/

and my code is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B91Bt7_YsWRZRVk1blJlRTNDeUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your div with id `topper` is covering your entire page and seriously your body is only half of the page remove `position:absolute` from `#topper`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code in the question. People are less likely to help you if even seeing your code requires more effort than the next question.

Comment: Just to add to @Akshay's comment. Whenever you position something absolutely, it removes that element from the document flow. This means that the body was just covering the topper div.

Comment: omg....
OK I see what wrong with my code...
thank u  a lot.

Comment: @Akshay Can you post your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your div with `id` `topper` is covering your entire page and seriously your body is only half of the page remove `position:absolute` from `#topper`

As a side note if you are trying to make a top bar remove the child elements from `topper` that are actual contents and set only those contents that are set for `topper`

Answer (score 0):

Just recommend a method to quick find the problem like that when I dealing with strange things in web development.[Inspect Elements In Website](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#inspect-element-line)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click to buttons because they was covered by `#topper`.

So change `z-index` of `#topper` to `0` (or higher)
Then apply `positionn: absolute` to your button with `z-index` higher than `#topper`.